# Anonymous function assignement in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, indentation, anonymous-function

I'm struggling to make the following code work:

```
class Elements
    constructor: ->

    loadAll: ->
        success = (data) =>
            doSomething
            doSomethingElse

        $.post bla success
```

It thinks everything after doSomething is not part of the success callback body.

Edit: I didn't realise CS was space/tab sensitive. TextMate doesn't help with it; Is there a better IDE for CS?

Comment: A CoffeeScript bundle for TextMate is just a google away: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle

Comment: I use it, and it's nice for coloring but it doesn't help with space/tabs issue. I will try to find something... In Eclipse you can tell it to use space for tabs.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? I don't use TextMate but as popular as it is with programmers I'm certain it has configurable tab/space settings, probably on a per-filetype basis.

Comment: TextMate does let you specify tabs/spaces on a per-filetype basis (look in the bar at the bottom), and you can use the **Text** menu / **Convert** / **Tabs to Spaces** tool to correct your existing document.

Comment: You can also use **View** / ** Show Invisibles **, which will show tab characters (though this may be too subtle—@Jeremy's solution is usually preferable).

Answer (score 2):

TextMate is probably the *best* editor for CoffeeScript, with a bundle maintained by CoffeeScript creator Jeremy Ashkenas. (The bundle is also compatible with [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), which is a nice cross-platform alternative.) The solution here is to:

1. Convert all tabs to spaces in your existing files (as Jeremy suggested in his comment), and
2. Switch to **Soft Tabs** using this switcher at the bottom of the window:

[image]

That way, when you hit the Tab key, the number of specified spaces is inserted. By avoiding the use of actual tab characters, you avoid the inevitable confusion that results from *n* spaces looking the same to a human as *1* tab, but being ambiguous to the compiler.

The norm in the CoffeeScript community is 2 spaces, but there are plenty of folks using 4 spaces (which is the official standard in Python-land); just pick one and stick with it.

If you do decide to make the switch to Sublime Text 2, you can add these lines to your `Base File.sublime-settings` preferences file to force soft tabs with the given number of spaces:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

In sum: Hard tabs and languages with significant whitespace don't mix. Configure your editor to use soft tabs, and CoffeeScript responsibly. :)

Comment: `4 spaces == tab` in most places (except browsers that for some reason decided that a tab should equal *8* spaces...)

Comment: @RicardoTomasi Right; if I were working with hard tabs, I'd use 4 spaces. But since I'm instead indenting code with 2 spaces, I'd like the "Tab" key to just mean "insert two spaces."